# how to use INPUT_PULLUP using pyfirmata2

Tags: python, arduino-uno, firmata

In Arduino IDE (C++ programming language) we can use `pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP)` to avoid using resistor, but here I'm using Arduino microcontroller and running `StandardFirmata` inside it, then I use python and `pyfirmata` library but I don't know how to call `INPUT_PULLUP`, and if I run the program the output will be true and false.

```
from pyfirmata2 import Arduino, util
    import time
    board = Arduino('COM6')
    iterator = util.Iterator(board)
    iterator.start()
    button = board.get_pin('d:2:i')
    while True:
        print(button.read())
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that pyfirmata supports pullup. You can try [Telemetrix](https://mryslab.github.io/telemetrix/) Telemetrix is similar to Firmata, but does not use 7bit bytes. You can view its API [here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/MrYsLab/telemetrix/blob/master/html/telemetrix/index.html). If you really need to use Firmata, then also look at [pymata4.](https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata4)